# Flutter type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I am trying to compare date and asper date i am doing some actioin, but I am getting following error.
**"type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast"**

*I am getting date from API in this format 25-09-2022*

var postList have all data from api(in this case i am getting start and end date from API)

following are my code:-

```
DateTime stdt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(postList.startDate.toString());
DateTime endt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(postList.endDate.toString());
DateTime crdt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now()) as DateTime;

if (stdt.isAtSameMomentAs(endt)){
        if(stdt.isBefore(crdt)){
             setState(() {
                   ComparisonText = "Past";
                   ContainerColor = Colors.red;
                 });
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWgIz.jpg)

Comment: Can you try parsing the `DateTime.now()` , `DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(DateTime.now().toString());`

Comment: Thank you soo much..its solved after adding toString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to compare string to date time in this line

```
if(stdt.isBefore(crdt))
```

try add .toString() like that

```
DateTime crdt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now().toSring());
```

Comment: DateTime crdt = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(DateTime.now().toString());

its solved with this code